# python regex - match two string

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if two strings are similar to each other ....
for example :

```
string1 = "Select a valid choice. **aaaa** is not one of the available choices."
string2 = "Select a valid choice. **bbbb** is not one of the available choices."
```

or

```
string3 = "Ensure this value has at most 30 characters (it has 40 chars)."
string4 = "Ensure this value has at most 60 characters (it has 110 chars)."
```

if I compare string1 to string2 it should return `True` and if I compare string1 to string3 it should return `False`.

Comment: Show us the regex you have tried.

Comment: it won't give string1 and 2 as true.

Comment: cant compare values coz string1 containg aaaa and string2 contains bbbb it ll return False instead True.

Comment: So you have to extract the relevant parts you want to compare. Please try it and include the result in your question.

Comment: Could you please spell formal definition of "equal" and "not equal" strings in your case. It's clear for human being, but computers are not humans, you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

```
def lev(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return lev(s2, s1)

    # len(s1) >= len(s2)
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = xrange(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1 # j+1 instead of j since previous_row and current_row are one character longer
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1       # than s2
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]

string1 = "Select a valid choice. aaaa is not one of the available choices."
string2 = "Select a valid choice. bbbb is not one of the available choices."
string3 = "Ensure this value has at most 30 characters (it has 40 chars)."
string4 = "Ensure this value has at most 60 characters (it has 110 chars)."

print lev(string1, string2) # => 4
print lev(string3, string4) # => 3
print lev(string1, string3) # => 49
```

code copied from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python)